# Ошибка You have an error in your SQL syntax; и Unknown column '' in 'field list'

Tags: php, sql

Доброго времени суток, помогите разобраться пожалуйста.
Создал форму, при загрузке на хостинг выдает ошибку :

Этот код работает без проблем на локальном OpenServer :

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO wp_db (ФИО, Дата_рождения, Телефон, Электронная_почта, Первый, Второй, Третий, Четвертый ) VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[birth]', '$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[email]', '', '', '', '')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo 'Новая запись успешно создана';
} else {
    echo "Ошибка: " . $sql . "<br>" .$conn->error;
}
```

А после закачки на хостинг форма при отправке выдает :

> > You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�ИО, Дата_рождения, Тел�' at line 1

После поиска информации по ошибке поставил sql переменные в ``

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_db` (`ФИО`, `Дата_рождения`, `Телефон`, `Электронная_почта`, `Первый`, `Второй`, `Третий`, `Четвертый`) VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[birth]', '$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[email]', '', '', '', '')";
```

После чего стал выдавать такую ошибку :

> Unknown column 'ФИО' in 'field list'

При этом поле ФИО существует в базе данных.

Конфигурации MySQL :
OpenServer : 5.6.26
Хостинг : 5.5.35-33.0

**Обновление**

Кодировка таблицы `utf8_general_ci`, в коде после коннекта к бд и выбора таблицы идет `mysql_query("set names utf8");` При создании таблицы в бд

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");
```

В самой форме прописано `accept-charset="UTF-8"`. То есть вроде как везде utf-8 стоит.

Comment: А кодировка в БД и при подключении совпадает и в тексте запроса ? может сделать set names utf-8, убедится что текст в utf, что база в utf

Comment: ну во-первых, я бы не советовал вам называть поля русскими имена, а во-вторых, если с кодировкой все нормально, как вариант попробуйте зайти в какой-нибудь phpmyadmin, там выбрать insert и оттуда скопировать поля в свой запрос